# Overriding templates when using Grappelli

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I'm using Grappelli with Django. When I follow the procedure as [outlined in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) to override a specific template for a specific model, it appears that Django (or Grappelli??) are struggling to render the template correctly.

I have copied the `change_form.html` file to the templates directory with the following subpath:

```
admin/properties/Calendar
```

where `properties` is the name of the app and `Calendar` is the name of the model for which I want to override the change form. Now the following appears

[image]

At least two things are not rendered correctly:

- The breadcrumb bar is much thinner and the crumbs are tightly aligned with the left border of the bar.
- The link for the history of changes is in the wrong place (it appears on the left), has the wrong style (no rounded edges) and appears twice.

I double checked that the correct template file is used by Django, so the mechanism as documented works albeit with the above described flaws. When I rename the duplicated template file or delete it from my app, everything looks fine again.

Before I dive into this, I was hoping someone could hint at what is going wrong here. All not overridden templates seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I read I suspect you copy the default admin `change_form.html` template and not the grapelli version, found at `grappelli/templates/admin/change_form.html`.

If you want to override a grapelli template, then you should use that as source!